# Jupyter ModuleError pyaudio

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()

```
  1 import pyaudio      
  2 import sys
  3 
  4 #sys.path.append('c:\\users\\neel.nath\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\lib\\site-packages')
  5 PyAudio = pyaudio.PyAudio     #initialize pyaudio
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'
```

I have got this error. Pyaudio is installed in the location which I have commented. Append function for sys.path does not work. How do I go about it?

Comment: Perhaps the Jupyter kernel is not using python3.6, instead python2 or a different version of python3 on your system.

Comment: I checked the jupyter kernel and it is using the same python 3.6.5 version which is installed in the system.